# plot using fct_relevel() dropping NA's

Tags: r, ggplot2, forcats

I have data that contains some NA values, and I am trying to make a plot as below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)

df<-data.frame(Y = rnorm(20, -6, 1),
                  X = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 20, replace = TRUE))

dfplot<- df   %>% mutate(X=fct_relevel(X, "yes"))%>%
  ggplot(.,
         aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=X))+
  geom_boxplot(size=1, width = 0.2, show.legend = F, outlier.shape = NA,
               position=position_nudge(x=0.3))+
  geom_jitter(show.legend = T, shape=21, width=0.2, size=2)+
  geom_crossbar(data=df %>% group_by(X) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Y), .groups="keep"),
                aes(x=X, ymin=mean, ymax=mean, y=mean), width = 0.2, show.legend = F)+

  labs(x="",
       y="%")

dfplot
```

[image]

however when I try to plot only the "yes" and "no" variables, dropping the "NA" using filter(X!="NA") I cannot relevel them to the correct order with "yes" as the first column. The same happens if I use `drop_na("X")` or `filter(!is.na(X))` instead of `filter(X!="NA")`

```
dfplot<- df %>% filter(X!="NA")  %>% mutate(X=fct_relevel(X, "yes"))%>%
  ggplot(.,
         aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=X))+
  geom_boxplot(size=1, width = 0.2, show.legend = F, outlier.shape = NA,
               position=position_nudge(x=0.3))+
  geom_jitter(show.legend = T, shape=21, width=0.2, size=2)+
  geom_crossbar(data=df %>% group_by(X) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Y), .groups="keep"),
                aes(x=X,ymin=mean, ymax=mean, y=mean), width = 0.2, show.legend = F)+

  labs(x="",
       y="%")

dfplot
```

[image]

Comment: `X != "NA"` test is X is the string "NA". I think you want `filter(!is.na(X))`

Comment: tried that too, still nothing. Sorry, shoud've it aded to OP. I will amend now.

Comment: Closer inspection - it is the geom_crossbar that is causing problems because you are giving it the data without the relevel

Comment: yep, this is it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is because you have provided the same data in 'geom_crossbar' without also specifying the removal of 'NA' values.

Try to "set.seed" at the beginning of the code block to make it fully reproducible.

The following should produce a plot with 'yes' and 'no' at the correct level.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(123456)

df <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(20, -6, 1),
               X = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 20, replace = TRUE))


dfplot <- df %>% filter(!is.na(X))  %>% mutate(X=fct_relevel(X, 'yes')) %>%
    ggplot(.,
           aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=X))+
    geom_boxplot(size=1, width = 0.2, show.legend = F, outlier.shape = NA,
                 position=position_nudge(x=0.3))+
    geom_jitter(show.legend = T, shape=21, width=0.2, size=2)+
    geom_crossbar(data=df %>% filter(!is.na(X)) %>% group_by(X) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Y), .groups="keep"),
                  aes(x=X,ymin=mean, ymax=mean, y=mean), width = 0.2, show.legend = F)+
    
    labs(x="",
         y="%")

dfplot
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the na.translate argument in scale_fill_discrete and set it to TRUE. NA values will then be mapped to your fill color. [Here](https://ggplot2tor.com/scales/scale_fill_discrete) is a minimal example on how to do that.

```
df<-data.frame(Y = rnorm(20, -6, 1),
               X = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 20, replace = TRUE))

dfplot<- df %>% 
  mutate(X=fct_relevel(X, "yes", "no"))%>%
  ggplot(.,
         aes(x=X, y=Y, fill=X))+
  geom_boxplot(size=1, width = 0.2, show.legend = F, outlier.shape = NA,
               position=position_nudge(x=0.3))+
  geom_jitter(show.legend = T, shape=21, width=0.2, size=2)+
  geom_crossbar(data=df %>% group_by(X) %>% summarise(mean=mean(Y), .groups="keep"),
                aes(x=X, ymin=mean, ymax=mean, y=mean), width = 0.2, show.legend = F)+
  
  labs(x="",
       y="%") +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.translate = TRUE)

dfplot
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to affect the order of the factors. Also tried `scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette ="Set3", na.translate=T)` which is the colour scheme I'm using with my actual data but nothing.